# How to synchronize new Notes from iPad to Mac

Tags: itunes, macos, notes.app, data-synchronization

I upgraded my iTune to iTune 11, and no longer find the option to synchronize note. I do not like to use iCloud (no WiFI or Cellular), but cannot figure a way to synchronize (or download) the note on my iPad to my Mac's Note.app.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4191):

> You can sync with the Notes app using IMAP or iCloud. Syncing Notes using iTunes is no longer supported on OS X v10.8 and later.

There may be a possibility that it could still work, as it is specifically mentioned later in the article:

> If you want to sync notes with iTunes instead of using the over-the-air feature, disable Notes sync for the account using Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars or Settings > iCloud.

Though when I disabled Notes on the iPad, then synced to iTunes, the info pane never showed Notes as an option. I would perform the following steps to give it a fair shot:

- On the iPad -> Settings -> iCloud - disable notes
- On the iPad -> Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars - make sure no other service is using Notes
- On the Mac -> Notes -> Accounts - make sure Notes is turned off in all accounts.

According to the documentation, this should force iTunes to recognize that no sync options are available and provide some option to sync Notes, but it didn't "just work" for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync Notes between arbitrary devices using any IMAP mail account, like  Gmail. If you enable Notes for the corresponding account on all devices you have wireless notes synching.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @brockangelo's answer, it seems there is no offline mechanism to automatically sync new notes from your iPad to your Mac.

However, there may be a way to transfer existing notes. The app "[Notebooks for iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notebooks-for-ipad/id372370048?mt=8)" supports importing from the Notes app, as well as iTunes File Sharing. This means (in theory) you could import your notes into the Notebooks app, and then put them on your Mac via your iPhone's "Apps" tab in iTunes.

From there, you could copy and paste them into Notes.app on your Mac, use an AppleScript to import them, or use the files directly.

---

*Additional notes: I had never heard of the Notebooks app before researching this answer. I have not tried this method; it is only a concept. I searched a community-built [compilation](http://brettterpstra.com/ios-text-editors/) of iOS text editors, and found no other iPad apps that support both features. Yes, this answer suggests a dirty workaround, and it should be avoided if possible.*